# Ability to drag a window using an element in WebView (Cocoa, Swift)

Tags: css, swift, cocoa, webview, wkwebview

I build a web-based Cocoa app that has a WebView stretched to the whole window. The top bar of the app has tabs, controls and some unused area which I would like to use for giving user an ability to drag the window (like many apps do). Chrome apps and Electron have `-webkit-app-region: drag` CSS property for doing this. What about WKWebView in Cocoa?
[image: App top bar sketch]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `-[NSWindow isMovableByWindowBackground]` is set. Then, assuming nothing on `WKWebView` consumed mouse events, the drag should work.